# Generate vertex texture value and faces to a obj

Tags: javascript, three.js, arcore

I'm using the GLTFExporter lib to export a .obj file loaded with the OBJLoader, on the loaded .obj I want to generate vertex textures fields, my .obj is missing the *vt* values.

**Is there any way to generate the vt values?**

I've tried this..

```
function loadBlockObject() {
    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg');
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set(4, 4)

    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: texture
    });

    var loader = new OBJLoader();
    loader.load('models/obj/walt/block.obj', function (obj) {
        obj.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material = material;
            }
        });

        obj.scale.multiplyScalar(4);
        obj.position.set(400, 0, 0);
        scene1.add(obj);

    });
}
```

Just to see if by adding a texture on the material would add the vt values, but yea it didn't work.

I should mention that i'm rendering this in a Android ARCore SceneView.

Comment: To clarify texture coordinates are not added automatically by `three.js` when adding a texture to a material. If they are missing, it's best to import your asset in a DCC tool like Blender and then author proper texture coordinates. Depending on the model, generating uvs in code does not always produce usable results.